# Exclusion of Duplicate Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an EmployeeList Table that consists of data from a Company Table and an Employee Table. An Employee can be Active in multiple companies at once, so I need a query that selects an Employee's record only from one of the companies, based on certain scenarios, which I will include below.

1. John Doe is Active in both Primary Company and in Secondary Company. I need to report only his record from Primary Company, and ignore his record in Secondary Company.
2. John Doe is Active only in Secondary Company, so his record for that company needs to be reported.
3. John Doe was Active in both Primary Company and in Secondary Company yesterday. Today, he was Terminated from Primary Company, so his record for Secondary Company needs to be reported.

I've tried to exclude any records where the Company is 'Secondary Company' AND the Employee is reported twice on the EmployeeList, in other words they are Active in both companies at once, but this is not following the parameters set forth by Scenario # 3.

```
DELETE FROM EmployeeList 
WHERE CompanyName = 'Secondary Company'
AND EmployeeID IN (SELECT EmployeeID 
                   FROM EmployeeList 
                   GROUP BY EmployeeID 
                   HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
                  );
```

Only one record should be reported per Employee, based on the parameters set forth by the 3 scenarios I included.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you trying to modify the data or just do a `SELECT` according to your rules?

Comment: Do you really want to delete the record if they are inactive or do you want a view that shows one of each employee with the criteria that they are active in the table? Also what are the fields in the table, and do you need to return all the fields?

Comment: How do you know which company is primary for a given employee? Surely your data does not really use "Primary Company" for Company Name as a way to identify this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You phrase this as a reporting need, not as a storage need, so if that is true, I certainly wouldn't advise any delete operation.

Also, I noticed the comment by The Gambill and realized that 'Secondary Company' was stored in 'Company Name'.  As he says, you'll have to have better criteria for what constitutes a primary company.  In this answer, I'll just assume you've got a field called 'isPrimaryCompany'.

You might want to consider doing a cte or subquery which performs a rank of each row based on whether it is a primary record or not.  This would be filtered to include active records only.  Then, outside of that cte or subquery, select all rows with rank = 1 for each employee.

I'm making some assumptions about your table structure and naming, but you can adapt the following as appropriate:

```
with

    ranked as (

        select        *,
                      [rank] = row_number() over(
                          partition by employeeId 
                          order by case when isPrimaryCompany = 1 then 0 else 1 end
                      )
        from          EmployeeList -- which is not really at the 'employee' level
        where         status = 'active'

    )

    select     *
    from       ranked 
    where      rank = 1
```